# Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' than fatal error

Tags: php, string, wordpress

Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' in /home/liveep5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin/inc/tools.php on line 591

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/liveep5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin/inc/tools.php on line 591

```
$attachment_metadata['sizes']['croped-image-' . $width . '-' . $height] = array(
        'file'          => $pathinfo['basename'],
        'width'         => $width,
        'height'        => $height,
        'mime-type'     => get_post_mime_type($attachment_id)
    );
    // wp update attachment metadata
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_metadata );

    $ratio_value = $height / $width;`$image .= '<img class="wp-post-image croped-image ' . $custom_class . '" data-ratio="' . $ratio_value . '" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height .'" src="' . $croped_image_url . '" alt="'. $alt_value .'">';
```

looks for another questions i see that I`m noob, where i need change this code.
help me, please.

Thank you!

Comment: Dump the variable: `var_dump($attachment_metadata)` and see what it actually contains. And what line is 591?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely $attachment_metadata doesn't contain a key 'sizes' which contains an array. var_dump it like @magnus-eriksson suggested.